# Messenger Extensions Javascript SDK Error

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am Developing a chat bot in web using Messenger Extensions Javascript SDK.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#webview_on_web

It was working perfectly yesterday. But without having any changes from my side SDK is having some error from today morning [DATE: 22/06/2018]

```
ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at Object.reportError (messenger.Extensions.js:94)
    at Object.applyWithGuard (messenger.Extensions.js:94)
    at c (messenger.Extensions.js:158)
    at messenger.Extensions.js:75
```

Is facebook have done any changes in "Messenger Extensions Javascript SDK"?

Please do share here if you have any information about it.

Comment: i have the same issue since this morning too.  
It's OK if opening the webview with messenger app, but KO on web browser.  
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/799387066925109/?disable_redirect=0